# Parsing XML with Javascript by <FIELD>

Tags: javascript, xml

I am attempting to parse an XML document with javascript using a word searched by a user in the intital interface. My current `.js` function is as follows:

```js
function lookup(){
     console.log("called");
     $("#content").empty();
     var wordToFind = $('#word').val().toLowerCase();
     console.log(wordToFind);
     ...
}
```

However, I am lost from here as my XML is organized like this:

```xml
<row>
    <FIELD1>name</FIELD1>
    <FIELD2>name2</FIELD2>
    <FIELD3>name3</FIELD3>
</row>
.
.
.
<row>
    <FIELD1>name4</FIELD1>
    <FIELD2>name5</FIELD2>
    <FIELD3>name6</FIELD3>
</row>
```

My hope is to have the `lookup()` function in my `.js` file parse through the `.xml` file and find the contents of the `<FIELD2>` section and return `<FIELD3>` if the contents of `<FIELD2>` equal the word inputted by the user.

This is a dumbed down example of what I am trying to do, but I think answering this will help me solve my problem and learn the process of using javascript and xml together. What needs to be added to `lookup()` to accomplish this task? I am new to both so as much explanation of what/why/how as possible is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TRY IT MAYBE HELP:

```
       <script>
            var text, parser, xmlDoc;

            text = "<row>" +
                    "<FIELD1>name1</FIELD1>" +
                    "<FIELD2>name2</FIELD2>" +
                    "<FIELD3>name3</FIELD3>" +
                    "</row>";


            if (window.DOMParser) {
                // code for modern browsers
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
            } else {
                // code for old IE browsers
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
            }


            var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row")[0].childNodes;

            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                alert(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }

        </script>
```